# Why not show Secure in front of URL in my Chrome browser when I open live server from VS code?

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code, url, google-chrome-extension, vscode-liveshare

Why not show Secure in front of URL in my Chrome browser when I open live server from VS code?
Please If anyone know my problem solution tell me the reason?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dTeG.png)
What is the reason of my problem?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that the `Not Secure` badge in the address bar indicates is that the webpage doesn't have a valid SSL certificate (or that there is no certificate at all, `http://` vs `https://`).

It is not something you need to worry about while developing a website. When you look to host the site, you should look into getting a certificate from a service like "Let's Encrypt" or using a host that provides a free certificate.

---

One thing to note is that you should avoid using a self signed certificate (as opposed to getting a signed certificate from an authority) if you plan to publish the site to be accessible to people other than yourself. A self signed certificate will result in the same warning in most browsers unless the user has a copy of the certificate in their certificate store (where certificates are stored). You can make it work on an individual computer or network, but it is easy enough to get a proper certificate. You only need to worry about renewing it if the place you get the certificate from doesn't have an auto renewal system.